# Is there a way to add outline/highlight your model?

Tags: modeling

I have seen a few tutorials where you can add outline around your models, unfortunatley none of thoe tutroials gave me the results I was looking for! is there a way to do this?(#1) instead of ?(#2)[image: #2][image: #1]
I would not like the lines to be visible inside the model( I am new to blender and to 3d art)

Comment: What exactly did you tried? Did you tried with freestyle?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=silhouette

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Render Properties tab: Enable Freestyle.
2. View Layer Properties tab: Make sure *External Contour* is the only edge type checked.

Comment: This works, but doesn't show the results in the 3D View, not even with the Rendered Viewport Shading option set. Is there a way to get it to show the results prior to rendering?

Comment: As far as I know, Freestyle is strictly a post-processing effect. :/